# Disabling button usage with timeout functions

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with jQuery.

I have such small function

```
setTimeout(player_attack,500);
setTimeout(mob_attack,700);
```

This is triggered by button. But there is a problem. User can click it quickly and its all messing up. So i want to disable button for a while.

But this:

```
$('#button_name').attr("disabled","disabled");
```

but it works.

But when I put:

```
$('#button_name').removeAttr("disabled","disabled");
```

it doesnt work anymore.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Should $('#button_name').removeAttr("disabled","disabled"); be $('#button_name').removeAttr("disabled"); For removeAttr you shouldn't need to specify a value, just an attribute.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$('#button_name').removeAttr("disabled");
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Atakuj').bind('click', function() {
    
    
    $("#Atakuj").prop("disabled", true);
    setTimeout(player_attack,500);
    setTimeout(mob_attack,700);
    $("#Atakuj").prop("disabled", false);
    $('#messages').prepend('<hr>');

This doesnt want to work still

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to use [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method:

```
$("#button_name").prop("disabled", false); // or true to make it disabled
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
$("#selector").attr("disabled", true); // or false
```

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rWY2e/) fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery docs recommend using the `.prop()` method rather than `.attr()` for changing the disabled property. (See [here](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) for more details.)

```
$('#button_name').prop("disabled", true); //or false
```

Comment: And here is a good reference on it. I was just looking into what was better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr